# How to access JSON with additional braces

Tags: json, node.js

I'm a expecting the json data from a webhook to look like this:

```
{"request": {"authentication": {"password": "1p2r9o6d4u5t1c","partnerid": "1296451"},"method": {"name": "SubmitUserTestResult","user_id": "3", "transcript_id": "5012658", "test_id": "10155", "test_name": "Productive People Quality Assurance Associate Test", "percentage": "8", "percentile": "73", "average_score": "8", "test_result": "FAIL", "reporturl": "http://assessments.getqualified.work/CreateNewPdf.aspx?transcriptid': '5012658", "time": "2017-11-08T06:56:22Z"}}}
```

However, it comes with an additional braces on both end like this:

```
{ '{"request": {"authentication": {"password": "1p2r9o6d4u5t1c","partnerid": "1296451"},"method": {"name": "SubmitUserTestResult","user_id": "3", "transcript_id": "5012658", "test_id": "10155", "test_name": "Productive People Quality Assurance Associate Test", "percentage": "8", "percentile": "73", "average_score": "8", "test_result": "FAIL", "reporturl": "http://assessments.getqualified.work/CreateNewPdf.aspx?transcriptid': '5012658", "time": "2017-11-08T06:56:22Z"}}}' }
```

My code looks like this:

```
receiveResult: function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

How can I access this data since it doesn't appear like a valid json?

Comment: Can you update the webhook to format the respose correctly ?

Comment: You will have to strip of the `{ '` and `' }` from the beginning and end first, and then parse it as JSON.

Comment: @TheRock3t I don't control the webhook.

Comment: Then strip out the start and the end of the string and deserialuse the rest

Comment: @TheRock3t it's not string. When I use .toString() on it and try .slice, I get something like this bject Object

Comment: @CBroe that has proved abortive since that data is an object.

Comment: I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object is not stringified then you can use following code :

```js
let invalidData = { '{"request": {"authentication": {"password": "1p2r9o6d4u5t1c","partnerid": "1296451"},"method": {"name": "SubmitUserTestResult","user_id": "3", "transcript_id": "5012658", "test_id": "10155", "test_name": "Productive People Quality Assurance Associate Test", "percentage": "8", "percentile": "73", "average_score": "8", "test_result": "FAIL", "reporturl": "http://assessments.getqualified.work/CreateNewPdf.aspx?transcriptid': '5012658", "time": "2017-11-08T06:56:22Z"}}}'  };

let  tempData = Object.keys(invalidData);
tempData += ':' + invalidData[tempData];

let validData = JSON.parse(tempData);

console.log(validData);
```

Comment: Hi Amit, this worked perfectly for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You should use regex to get your desired result. Try following :

```js
const regex = /(?:({"))[\s\S]*(?=('\s*}))/g;
const str = `{ '{"request": {"authentication": {"password": "1p2r9o6d4u5t1c","partnerid": "1296451"},"method": {"name": "SubmitUserTestResult","user_id": "3", "transcript_id": "5012658", "test_id": "10155", "test_name": "Productive People Quality Assurance Associate Test", "percentage": "8", "percentile": "73", "average_score": "8", "test_result": "FAIL", "reporturl": "http://assessments.getqualified.work/CreateNewPdf.aspx?transcriptid': '5012658", "time": "2017-11-08T06:56:22Z"}}}'  }`;



let data = JSON.parse(str.match(regex)[0]);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I get the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

Comment: can you send your code snippet. Because this code is working fine.